# Moving precisely without using Alt?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-onenote

For some application, like powerpoint and onenote, when you want to move the object like textbox or image precisely, you need to hold Alt to move it "pixel by pixel". How can I disable such feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hold the Alt key. Then it does not move pixel by pixel.

And if you **want** fine grained movement, hold the Alt key.

In tablet mode this may depend on the tablet. I find that on a Surface Pro 3, the on-screen keyboard's arrow keys move items pixel by pixel in PowerPoint and are perfect for positioning, whereas in OneNOte nothing I've tried on the on-screen keyboard does anything useful.

That does not bug me because I'm not trying to use OneNote for pixel perfect designs.

Comment: Actually the problem is sometime I dont have a keyboard with tablet, so I am looking for a solution. I think the possible way is to toggle between pixel by pixel and grained movement, or just set pixel by pixel for default behaviour.

Comment: I added a paragraph about tablets.